# To prove that $s= \sup (A)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, self-learning, supremum-and-infimum

Given that $s$ is upper bound for set $A$ (of reals). And given $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists a \in A\ s.t.\ s - \epsilon < a$

Now I assume that $b$ be any other  upper bound of $A$ and I need to prove that $s \leq b$.

Assume on the contrary that  $s > b$. Lets take $\epsilon = \frac{b - s}{2}$. So, $\exists a \in A\ s.t.\ s - \epsilon < a .$ Simplifying we get $ \frac{s+b}{2} < a $
Now it suffices to prove that  $ b <  \frac{s+b}{2} $. Now we have $s > b$ and so $\frac{s}{2}+\frac{b}{2} > \frac{b}{2}+\frac{b}{2}$ and so $\frac{s+b}{2} > b $. so we have $ b <  \frac{s+b}{2} < a $. This contradicts that $b$ is upper bound for $A$. Thus assumption $s >b$ is false.

Please check if its correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a typo. You want to take $\epsilon = \frac{s - b}{2}$ not $\frac{b - s}{2}$. Other than that you are fine.

Comment: If $s>b$ then you choice of epsilon is negative!

Comment: oh yes in my notebook I have taken mod.i forgot to mention it here. Thanks

Comment: Note that based on your condition of "$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists a \in A\ s.t.\ s - \epsilon < a$" that the $s$ is actually the least upper bound, i.e., supremum, which you've basically proven (apart from the typo mentioned in the $2$ comments above).